# Copy only first entered value into cell

Tags: vba, excel, cell

I have this problem: in Excel file I have two sheets. In first sheet I am entering values, changing values, deleting values... Sometimes, in one cell I enter value like this `125+138+458`

Now, I need to copy values into next sheet, but only values that have been first entered into first sheet.

Comment: Do you mean, in first sheet we enter `111` to `A1`, then enter `222` to `A1`, you want `111` to show up on second sheet? I don't think this is possible without VBA.

Comment: any ideas about VBA code? I dont know how to write that code? please help

Comment: I added `vba` tag, hopefully someone familiar with VBA will have the answer.

Comment: thanks...I hope that someone will find answer

Comment: Start with this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213612

Answer (score 0):

I found this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim VRange As Range, cell As Range
Dim Msg As String
Dim ValidateCode As Variant
Set VRange = Range("B119:H130")
For Each cell In Target
    If Union(cell, VRange).Address = VRange.Address Then
        Cells(cell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = Date & " " & Time
        Cells(cell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = cell.Value
    End If
Next cell End Sub
```

that is ok, because now I have time of change and value that change...I need to have cell value of header of column and only first change of cell.
how to do that?

Answer (score -2):

in your 2nd sheet, you can put this in a cell: ´=Sheet1!A1".

Sheet 1:

```
A1: 50
B1: =A1 + 20
```

Sheet 2:

```
A1: =Sheet1!A1  //Will output "50"
B1: =Sheet1!B1  //Will output '70"
```

Change `A1`from sheet 1 to any other value, and the 2 cells in sheet 2 will update as well.

Comment: no...I would like to have in sheet 2 value for A1- to stay 50